# Remove grey vertical bars in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, grids, guides

I am getting the following lines in Sketch, what do they mean and how can I remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Those are the Layout grid guides – they are just helpers and do not export with the JPGs (for example). Their purpose is to help out with aligning your layout.

You can disable them by pressing on the "View" dropdown in the horizontal top bar and removing the tick from "Show Layout".

[image: Show Layout enabled]

You can also go into the Layout Settings screen and adjust the way these layout guides show. Currently, you have "Fill Grid" selected. Instead, you can choose "Stroke Outline" for an alternative view.

[image: Layout Settings]